# Prove that convolution of two vectors is equivalent to matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, convolution

I'm following a course on image processing and we have the following statement

$$ w = w_1 * w_2 = w_1 \cdot w_2 $$
$$w_1 \in R_{m \times 1}, w_2 \in R_{ 1 \times n }$$

How can one prove this with the formula for 2D discrete convolution ?

$$(w * f)(x,y) = \sum_{s=-a}^a \sum_{t=-b}^b w(s, t) \dot f(x-s, y-t) $$

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44439/21075).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get the 2D discrete convolution correctly:

$$ (w*f)(x,y) = \sum_s\sum_t w(s,t)f(x-s,y-t)$$

where $s,t$ ranges are deduced from the dimensions of $w$ and $f$. In your case
these dimensions are $m\times 1$ and $1\times n$ respectively. If we use 0-based indices than we get
$t = 0$ and $x-s=0 \longrightarrow s = x$. Thus the convolution for this special case becomes

$$ (w*f)(x,y) = \sum_{s=x}\sum_{t=0} w(s,t)f(x-s,y-t) =
 w(x,0)f(0,y)
$$ i.e., the whole sum has only one element.
That element is the same as  $(w\cdot f)_{x,y}$ where $w\cdot f$ is the matrix product of $w$ and $f$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $$x - s = 0$$ because f is a row vector, and since you're indexing in 0 we can't access another line than that ?

Comment: @gordon_freeman: yes, this is what I meant. For the same reason the elements of the product matrix consist of single scalar products instead of sums of products.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much ! I penned out the proof myself and this makes sense.